# Minus one date from another in MySQL request?

Tags: php, mysql

I have table with `start_date` and `end_date`. I need to find the duration (`end_date-start_date`). Can someone suggest how I can do so in the query? Will I get a new variable with this somehow like `duration=end_date-start_date` in the query?

EDIT 
If I use mminus it gives me:

> 2012-07-01 minus 2012-01-01 = 600

How can it be 600 days in 6 months as 2011-07-27 - 2011-07-06 = 21? So i assume it's days?
Is there function to get actually how many months it even if date is in middle of month. 
e.g. like "3rd june" and "27 july" is 2 month

Comment: You mean you want the duration in days?

Answer (score 3):

use [`PERIOD_DIFF`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_period-diff)

Returns the number of months between periods P1 and P2. P1 and P2 should be in the format YYMM or YYYYMM. Note that the period arguments P1 and P2 are not date values.  so try

```
SELECT PERIOD_DIFF(
                   DATE_FORMAT('2011-07-27','%Y%m'),
                   DATE_FORMAT('2011-06-03','%Y%m')
                  ) AS durationInMonths
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know DateTime different, you can use TimeDiff

```
select 
 (Hour(Duration) / 24)/365 as Year, 
 (Hour(Duration) / 24)%365 as Day, 
 (Hour(Duration) % 24) as Hours, 
 MINUTE(Duration) as Minutes, 
 SECOND(Duration) as Seconds
 from
(
SELECT ADDTIME(NOW(),'1000:27:50') as end_datetime, NOW() as start_datetime,
TIMEDIFF(ADDTIME(NOW(),'1000:27:50'), NOW()) AS Duration
) x;
```

If you want to know Date different, you can use DateDiff()

```
select DATEDIFF('2011-06-06','2011-05-01');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use * but to get duration, you need to add extra column after it

```
select *, DATEDIFF(updated_at, created_at) from users;
```

TO have the best practice, it is better naming u for user, duration for extra column.
So you can see Duration title at the top. It is good if you export your sql procedure to excel.

```
select u.*, DATEDIFF(updated_at, created_at) as duration from users u;
```

Also from your php or rails code, you can call that given variable name. In rails,

```
users =User.find_by_sql("select u.*, DATEDIFF(updated_at, created_at) as duration from users u")

users.first.duration
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT end_date - start_date AS duration FROM table ...
```

Comment: Thnks, i need to do "SELECT * FROM mytable" is there way to still add this without need to name each column instead of *?

Comment: You shouldn't use `SELECT *` to begin with, but try this: `mytable.*, (mytable.end_date - mytable.start_date) as duration`

Comment: Why its bad to use * if i need all the fields i requested request from table?

Comment: Can you give full query i cannot seem to figure it out.

Why its bad to use * if i need all the fields i requested request from table?

Comment: It is not possible for anyone to give you the full query as you did not provide the query you want to add this duration to.